# loop with python or ahk with LMB

Tags: loops, click, autohotkey

have a nice day, could someone help me? I would like to make a program but I don't know how. .ahk if possible or python ..in ahk i did this

```
LAlt::
loop
{
   click, down
   break
}
return
```

this does, when you press alt and release it, this holds down LMB until you click with LMB. My question is, how do I do it only with LMB. It would be necessary to add a key for PAUSE.
I don't understand much about programming, I did it with tutorials. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know if I understand well what you want, but i think you need something like this?

```
LButton::
If (var = "Pressed")
{
    Click, Left, , Up
    var := "Unpressed"
}
Else
{
    Click, Left, , Down
    var := "Pressed"
}
Return
```

As a tip to begins with ahk, you can use 'https://www.macrocreator.com/', in this program you can make a script very easily and you can see what it writes in ahk.

Like this:
[image]

You can export an AHK file, or just copy the script in the right side of the screen.